# Various issues with remove

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have a script that removes some files.  I'm running into the error where remove-item doesn't always remove them all.  I saw [get-childitem remove include recurse](https://serverfault.com/questions/199921/force-remove-files-and-directories-in-powershell-fails-sometimes-but-not-always) but I get this error:

```
Get-ChildItem : Missing an argument for parameter 'Include'. Specify a
parameter of type 'System.String[]' and try again.
At D:\Scripts\powershell\myScript.ps1:39 char:47
+                Get-ChildItem $dirPathToRemove -Include -Recurse | Remove-Item -R ...
+                                               ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

My code for the remove looked like this:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem $dirPathToRemove -Include -Recurse | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

So I tried another solution at that link and tried this other suggestion (I think) at the link:

```bsh
$fullPath = (Resolve-Path $dirPathToRemove).ProviderPath
powershell -Command '$cmd.exe /c rd /s /q $fullPath'
```

But I get this:

```
+ $cmd.exe /c rd /s /q $fullPath
+           ~
You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.
At line:1 char:11
+ $cmd.exe /c rd /s /q $fullPath
+           ~
Unexpected token 'c' in expression or statement.
```

The issue was similar without the `-Command` and just using `$cmd.exe`.

I have PowerShell 4.

Comment: What is not clear about the error message? The parameter `-Include` requires an argument. You need to tell the command *what* to include, e.g. `-Include '*.txt'`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be given with the $dirPathToRemove I give it?  Should I just give it *?  It seems redundant to me.

Comment: Again, the parameter `-Include` expects an argument. If you use that parameter you MUST provide an argument. If you don't want to provide the argument you MUST NOT use that parameter. There is no requirement to use the parameter. I don't know what else to tell you.